# Facebook search public photos by hashtag

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I work with Facebook API SDK. I'm trying to get all public photos using https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=xxxx|xxxxx&q=%23hashtag&type=post

But I have a problem: result contains only **shared** photos in first account. When i'm posting photo without share, search not found it.

Otherwise, I have another account where I'm posted photo and share it, but photo is not found too.

Who knows, how can I get all public photos with hastag using **FQL** or **graph search**

Addition:

Few days ago - facebook search is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with facebook developers, I got the answer:

> Facebook API does not support searching for hashtags.
>
> %23 is just the URL encoded version of a # which gets decoded on a
>   server generally so it still won't work. For example if I wanted to
>   search for #YOLO I would just say q=YOLO with no # or it's URL encoded
>   form.
>
> It's just something that the api doesn't support at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has officially deprecated the post search type. Im not sure when exactly but I can tell you I tried today (10/15/2014) and its a no go.

Comment: Graph API will be deprecated on Thursday, 30 April 2015